# DNN off-site link querystrings added

Tags: hyperlink, content-management-system, query-string, dotnetnuke

We're having an issue with DNN. When we create a link to a fully qualified domain on a different portal, querystrings get added automatically: WebSyncID and sessionGUID. How do I shut this off?

Comment: That is not an out of the box DNN thing. You must have some httpmodule or something that is configured and injecting.

Comment: It ended up being Silverpop tracking code that was doing this. Code removed, and issues vanished.